# 404 Error When Running Rake Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using rails 5 and am trying to run some basic tests. I updated my `database.yml` to use the same database whether on development or test environments.

The following tests returns a 404 error but when I start up my development server and go to the same url, everything works fine. So far all of the tests I have run that query the database return 404 errors.

Here is one of my tests.

```
test "should get cms page" do
    get "/reviews"
    assert_response :success
end
```

Error:

```
....E

Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_cms_page:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:16:in `cms_page'
test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'


bin/rails test test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:10
```

Comment: have you created any page in cms in test database?

Comment: @mark I have put a object in my fixture that corresponds to the object being queried in the database. When I run rake test I still get the same 404 error. Maybe the fixtures aren't loading?

Comment: Hmm.. maybe try stubbing the find call on the page model, will answer properly in a sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've created a fixture for a sample page, let's call it 'review_page', then try

```
test "should get cms page" do
  before do
    allow(StaticPage).to receive(:find).and_return(review_page)
  end
  ...

end
```

That assumes that the StaticPage model is receiving find in your controller - without the rest of the controller code it's impossible to tell

EDIT: The above works for RSpec, I think the syntax is the same with other frameworks